# I want to know if I've to rewrite my code for Android

Tags: javascript, java, browser, mobile-website

If I make a website with HTML,CSS & JS, I can run this in PC browsers. Would I also be able to run it in Android mobile browsers? Or I have to use different programming language like Java? Also, I want to know is, Android apps like Facebook, Twitter or Instagram, what languages are compulsory to make them?

Comment: no, you don't have to rewrite your website in Java - since websites are not written in Java

Comment: Yes, all/major mobile and PC browsers run HTML, CSS & JS, that's the very thing they do. And to make android apps you have plenty of options using Java, JavaScript, and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the core of every browser, mobile or not, is JavaScript. You can absolutely build a website that runs on them. However, you will have to mind what is actually compatible for those. You can manually check to see if a certain method or object is supported in different browsers by using a tool like https://caniuse.com/  or you could set up an automated solution that would run against your test suite (you could also test with these tools manually, but automation is always preferred) with a tool like https://www.browserstack.com/

As far as your second question, android apps are all written in Java, not to be confused with JavaScript and have to be compiled to run on android. You'll need a compiler like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/oxygen/1a/eclipse-ide-java-developers)

Edit: as someone else pointed out, you can also use a tool that might compile html/javascript into a native app with a tool like [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) or [NativeScript](https://nativescript.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any ESNEXT features and the browser supports the features you're using (https://caniuse.com/), you will be able to use the website on a phone, yes.

If you want it to be a native application (i.e. one you can download from the app store), you could learn a language like Java OR use [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/), which allows you to make mobile apps with similar language syntax to web development.